# how to double nest angular ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a template which is constructed in the following way...

```
<div ng-repeat="itemEntry in itemEntry">
   <!-- content -->
    <section class="product-view-wrapper" ng-repeat="productView in itemEntry.Productview">
      <div class="slide" ng-repeat="productImg in itemEntry.productImgs">
        <img ng-src="{{productImgs.img}}"/>
      </div>
     <!-- Content -->
 </section>
 </div>
```

Is it possible to nest two repeats inside an `ng-repeat`? if so based on the example above is this the correct html method?

i also have a  json file which looks like the following:

```
    image: "http://www.colette.fr/media/push/swa_mmm_001255.jpg",
                                productTitle: "Ipath lowrunner",
                                productDesc: "Low skateshoes - Grey",
                                user: "knows",
                                price: "$17",
                                productImgs: [
                                                {img: "http://www.colette.fr/media/push/swa_mmm_001255.jpg"},
                                                {img: "http://www.colette.fr/media/push/paddin265.jpg"}
                                ]
                            },
```

However i have noticed the `productImg` content does not appear when view through inspect element. Again is the correct structure when double nesting an ng-repeat function - if this even can be done?

[click on demo for a more in depth example](http://plnkr.co/edit/YhxP0WcuHiPqR6LIdjCP?p=preview)

Comment: It can be done, take a look at other questions about this issue http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=nested+ng-repeat+

Answer (score 3):

You aren't repeating over the proper array within the nested repeat. I scaled your demo down to just relevant html for the question

```
<section class="product-view-wrapper" ng-repeat="productObject in itemEntry">
  <!-- each loop of the <section> will output from productObject contained in itemEntry array -->
  <h3>{{productObject.productDesc}}</h3>
  <img ng-src="{{productObject.image}}" height="120px">
  <h4>Repeating images</h4>
   <!-- want to loop over array contained in each productObject -->
  <div class="slide" ng-repeat="productImg in productObject.productImgs" style="float:left">
    <img ng-src="{{productImg.img}}" height="80px" />
  </div>
  <hr style="clear:both">

</section>
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/xLuqkO8hctzWlLWNpnU2?p=preview)**</kbd>